# Не сортируются числа в массиве и неверно рассчитывается время

Tags: java, массивы, инкапсуляция

Есть следующее задание:
Создайте класс с именем StopWatch для представления секундомера.

Класс StopWatch должен содержать:

- Скрытые поля данных startTime и endTime с getter-методами.
- Безаргументный конструктор, который инициализирует startTime с текущим временем.
- Метод с именем start(), который сбрасывает startTime до текущего времени.
- Метод с именем stop(), который присваивает endTime текущее время.
- Метод с именем getElapsedTime(), который возвращает прошедшее время на секундомере в миллисекундах.

Нарисуйте UML-диаграмму класса StopWatch, а затем реализуйте этот класс. Напишите клиент этого класса — программу, которая вычисляет время выполнения сортировки 100 000 чисел методом выбора.

2 проблемы:

1. не сортируется массив;
2. не похоже что время считается верно…

Вот код:

```
import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StopWatch {

    /* поля данных */
    private static long startTime;
    private static long endTime;

    /* Метод main */
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        StopWatch time = new StopWatch();

        int[] list = new int [100000];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            list[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100000);

        }
    /* Сортировка массива */
        Arrays.sort(list);
        System.out.println("\n Сортировка массива: ");
        for (int num : list) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        time.stop();
        System.out.println("\n Время прошло в миллисекундах " + time.getElapsedTime());

    }

    /* Безаргументный конструктор, который инициализирует startTime с текущим временем */

    StopWatch () {
        startTime = currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /*  Скрытые поля данных startTime и endTime с getter-методами */
    public static long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public static long getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    /* сбрасывает startTime до текущего времени */
    public long start() {
        return startTime = currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /* Присваивает endTime текущее время */
    public long stop() {
        return endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /* Возвращает прошедшее время на секундомере в миллисекундах */
    public static long getElapsedTime() {
        return endTime - startTime;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, где ошибка?
P.S.
Поменяла сортировку. Сортировка теперь есть. Методы вызвала. Я так понимаю, теперь работает верно программа?

Comment: В логике сортировки что-то не то. Почему если `currentMin` меньше значения в `list` вы присваиваете значение из `list`? Я так понимаю должно быть наоборот, если `list[j]` меньше текущего минимального значения, то его необходимо обновить.

Comment: Потом по заданию у вас `StopWatch` должен содержать конструкторы, методы и т.д., а вы это в `Object` какой-то запихнули, зачем и почему?

Comment: Где находится определение метода `currentTimeMillis`, который вызывается из конструктора? И зачем его вообще туда писать?

Comment: @RomanC, там статический импорт указан для этого метода :)

Comment: @Nowhere Man, вот здесь проблема, видимо нет понимания... я вывожу строку System.out.println(time.selectionSort()); и программа ругается, что не задан аргумент. А где он должен быть задан? Я еще только учусь и пытаюсь понять, поэтому прошу объяснить. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ваш вопрос неактуален, так как метод `selectionSort` был удалён

Comment: Исправленный код у вас работает, однако считается **общее время** программы, включая создание данных, **библиотечную** _быструю_ сортировку и их вывод.  Такая реализация не слишком соответствует первоначальным требованиям к вашей программе: _написать программу, которая вычисляет время выполнения сортировки 100 000 чисел **методом выбора**._  Вывод 100 тысяч чисел в одну строку займёт больше всего времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StopWatch {

    /* поля данных */
    private static long startTime;
    private static long endTime;

    /* Метод main */
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        StopWatch time = new StopWatch();

        int[] list = new int [100000];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            list[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100000);

        }
        /* Сортировка массива
        Arrays.sort(list);
        System.out.println("\n Сортировка массива: ");
        for (int num : list) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        } */
        time.start();
        time.selectionSort(list);
        time.stop();
        System.out.println("\n Время прошло в миллисекундах " + time.getElapsedTime());

    }

    /* Безаргументный конструктор, который инициализирует startTime с текущим временем */

    StopWatch () {
        startTime = currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /*  Скрытые поля данных startTime и endTime с getter-методами */
    public static long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public static long getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    /* сбрасывает startTime до текущего времени */
    public long start() {
        return startTime = currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /* Присваивает endTime текущее время */
    public long stop() {
        return endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /* Возвращает прошедшее время на секундомере в миллисекундах */
    public static long getElapsedTime() {
        return endTime - startTime;
    }
    public static void selectionSort(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            int minInd = i;
            int min = list[i];
            //цикл выбора наименьшего элемента
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[j] < min) {
                    //minInd - индекс наименьшего элемента
                    minInd = j;
                    min = list[j];
                }
            }
            list[minInd] = list[i];
            //меняем местами наименьший с sortArr[i]
            list[i] = min;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Имеет смысл либо перенести создание объекта `time` после инициализации массива случайных чисел, либо вызвать метод `time.start()` непосредственно перед сортировкой.  И ради бога, не нужно называть **массив** примитивов (array) с типом `int[]` _списком_ (list) -- это разные вещи.